# Drafting - Specifying multiple hole quantities

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing, drafting, holes

First post in this stack but curious on if there is a 'right' answer (within Australian or ISO standard) for how to quantify numerous holes of same size/properties on a drawing. In the past I've seen (assuming 4-holes of 8mm diameter)

- Ø8 4 Places
- Ø8 4-OFF
- Ø8 x4
- Ø8 (4)
- 4 x Ø8

Looking at AS 1100.101 (Technical Drawings) it seems to show the last option;
[image]

However, looking AS 1100.201 (Mechanical Engineering) I'm unable to find industry specific confirmation. (at a glance)

What I really want to know, is what do most of you consider 'best practice'. Or what is commonly used in the industry seeing as the standards have not been updated since 1992. If from country other than Australia, please note where you're 'best practice' is considered.

Comment: All the odd ones you mentioned seem fine.  Even ones seem to be a bit more ambiguous.

Comment: Have you checked any of the Engineering Drawing books? many exist and all cover this type of information...

Comment: 4x is the right way to do it in ISO.

Comment: I have seen most of these in practice (in drawing books and circulated product drawings) as Abel and Mike mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Joojaa, great to hear confirmation from specific standards. This is exactly what i'm after.